# Javascript platformer lever reader?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an HTML5/Javascript platformer (or at least trying to) and I'm wondering how to make it read something like this level plan below:

```
var simpleLevelPlan = '
......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#................#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#............#..
......##############..
......................';
```

I had to use single quotes because if I use the correct ones it will mess up the code format. A hash symbol represents wall or floor, the @ symbol represents the player's spawn point. How can I make a simple reading function and how does it work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to add the equal sign is what you get to proceed to the next level.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ` instead of ', and split the string by newlines:

```
var simpleLevelPlan = `
......................
..#................#..
..#..............=.#..
..#................#..
..#.@......#####...#..
..#####............#..
......#............#..
......##############..
......................`;

var level = simpleLevelPlan.split('\n');
```

Using that way, the following code represents the '@' in the level:

```
//coordinates: y  x
var at = level[4][4];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am using, although I couldn't get the code format for stack overflow to go with it. Also, Thanks!